# How to make all navbar <li>s the same width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Angular 4, Bootstrap 4 alpha 6 (css). I am trying to make each `<li>` the equal width (not 100% of the navbar). I was trying to use flex box but I cant get it to make them all equal.

I've tried several ways but each time the items will all be a fixed width but not the same width.

Heres an example of what I'm trying to do

[ ---item 1--- | ---item 2--- | ---item 3--- ]

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ng-container *ngIf="isLoggedIn">
      <span class="navbar-text">&nbsp;</span>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Dashboard <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="profileDropdownMenu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          My Account
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item">My Account</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item">My Account</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"  id="accountDropdownMenu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Profile
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/profile', 'view']">My Account</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/profile']">Edit my Profile</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
nav ul{
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 2px;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

nav li{
  width: 100%
}

.nav.navbar-nav > li{
border-right: 2px solid white;
}
```

EDIT: This works but I would prefer to use flex so that its done automatically

```
.nav.navbar-nav > li{
border-right: 2px solid white;
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Other ways I've tried

1)

```
.navbar ul.nav {
  !*margin: 0;*!
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  !*direction: rtl;*!
  table-layout: fixed;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.navbar ul.nav  li {
  !*float: right;*!
  display: table-cell;
  width: 20%;
  !*float: none;*!
  text-align: center;
  !*direction: rtl;*!
}
.navbar .nav > li:hover {
  background-color: #808080
}

.navbar .nav li:first-child a {
  !*border-left: 0;*!
  !*border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;*!
}

.nav.navbar-nav > li{
  !*width: 10%;*!
  border-right: 2px solid white;
}
```

2)

```
nav {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 0 0 ;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

nav ul{
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 2px;
  padding: 0;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 5px;
}

nav a {
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 10px 5px;
 }
```

Comment: Are you looking to just fill 100% of the Navbar component with the links, or do you want each link to take up exactly X width?

Comment: I would like each to fill up exactly X width. Sorry should have mentioned that

Comment: With Bootstrap 4 you can use `<div>` for your `.navbar-nav` (instead of a list) which opens it up to more easily ALSO use the grid system... but I've got to say; it requires such an excess of additional wrappers (wrapping each `.nav-item` in a `.col` which is in a row... in a container...) that it just feels like an ugly solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use `calc()` Basically by dividing 100% width by 3 each li will be 1/3 in width. Next you can set each "a" to 100% (width will be 100% of parent) and display:inline-block (so that width takes effect.

```
nav li{
  width: calc(100% / 3);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It changes the height of the navbar and all of the items are moved up or down and aren't vertically aligned

Comment: So do you want all "a" tags to take up the entire li width?

Comment: If not, just remove the "nav a" style.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't see how you can get them to be the same size without giving your `<nav>` some kind of width.  However, if you **do** give it a width, you can get all your child elements to be the same width using a combination of `display: table;` and `display: table-cell`.  It's all the niceties of `<table>` without the syntactic commitment.

```css
nav {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul {
  display: table;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

nav ul li {
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Fizz</li>
    <li>Buzz</li>
    <li>Foo</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```